# How to bind click and keydown to input field in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, click, keydown

I am working on freecodecamp's wikipedia viewers project. I have got a working example but there are few things that I can't figure out how to do.

First of all how do I execute the some AJAX request by typing in the input field and pressing enter or by clicking of the button?

Next, when I try to type in the input field and press enter, results show in the web page. But when I try to type and enter again, new results do not show but the previous results disappear and I have to type and press enter again to get new results.

I know there other posts using jQuery which I also don't understand and don't want to use jQuery just in plain JavaScript.

```js
var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&datatype=json&limit=10&origin=*&search=';
var inputSearch = document.myForm.search;
var searchBtn = document.myForm.searchBtn;
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var random = document.getElementsByClassName('random')[0];

random.addEventListener("click" , function(){
  window.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random");
});

function requestData ( e ) {
  var inputStr = e.target.value;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if ( request.readyState === 4 ) {
      if ( request.status === 200 ) {
        var dataObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var titles = dataObj[1];
        var descriptions = dataObj[2];
        var links = dataObj[3];
        document.myForm.innerHTML += "<h2><span>" + links.length + "</span> results for \"" + "<span>" + inputStr + "</span>" +"\" </h2>"; 
        list.innerHTML = "";
        for ( var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++ ) {
          var li = "<li><a target='_blank' href=" + links[i] + ">" + titles[i] + "</a></li>";
          list.innerHTML += li;
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log("Server responded with following error code : " + request.status);
      }
    }
  };
  
  if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
      console.log(e.type);
      request.open("GET" , url + inputStr);
      request.send(null);
      e.preventDefault();
  }

}

inputSearch.addEventListener("keydown" , requestData);
searchBtn.addEventListener("click" , requestData);
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/* CSS reset ends here */

body {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
 
}

.container-wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 height: 100vh;

}

header {
 /*background-color: #fc3e5b;*/
 padding: 80px 0;
}

header h1 {
 font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif; 
 font-size: 70px;
 padding: 30px 0 80px 0;
 color: #fc3e5b;
}

form input , form button {
 padding: 10px 8px;
 font-size: 22px;
 border: 1px solid #fc3e5b;
 outline: 0;
 display: inline;
 margin: 0;
}

form button {
 background-color: #fc3e5b;
 color: #fff;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 25px;
 margin-top: 32px;
}

h2 span {
 font-weight:bold;
 color: #fc3e5b;
}
.random {
 padding: 22px 7px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 margin: 20px 0 15px 0;
}

.random:hover {
 border: 5px solid #fc3e6b;
}

#list {
 width: 75%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#list li {
 padding: 16px 8px;
 background-color: #fc3e5b;
 margin: 12px 0;
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 22px;
}

#list li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title> Wikipedia Viewer </title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Oxygen" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="wikipedia.css">
</head>
<body>  
  
  <div class="container-wrapper">
   <header>
     <h1> Wikipedia Viewer </h1>
   <form action="" name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="search" /><button name="searchBtn">Search</button>
    <br>
    <button name="btnRandom" class="random"> Random<br>Article </button>
   </form>
 </header>
 
 <div class="container">
     <ul id="list"></ul>
 </div>
  </div>

  <script src="wikipedia.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your script returning anything from the server?

Comment: Yes, I am getting response json which I am rendering into the page. Its just the issues I have mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code, see this fiddle for working code [Ajax call on click of button](https://jsfiddle.net/lamp03/xk7pkwu5/2/)

Check if it is working according to your needs.

Here are this list of changes that I made to your code :-

- I have changed the "keydown" event to "keyup" event, because on
  "keydown" we didn't receive the value of key pressed.
- I have    separated the function call on click event of search button
  and input key event to make it little bit clear.
- I have given id to search input box to get its value on "requestData()" function call.
- If we have  (instead of input type = "button") inside form then on click of button form gets submitted.
- I have added "event.preventDefault()" as first line in "requestData()" because on pressing enter button form is submitting automatically.
- Added a paragraph to show result statistics
- Changed this line `document.myForm.innerHTML +=` to `document.getElementById("results_stats").innerHTML`

Hope this helps you.

HTML :-

```
<div class="container-wrapper">
<header>
  <h1> Wikipedia Viewer </h1>
  <form action="" name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="txt_search" /><input type="button" name="searchBtn" value="Search"/>
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="btnRandom" class="random" value="Random Article"/>
  <p id="results_stats"></p>
  </form>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT :-

```
    var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&datatype=json&limit=10&origin=*&search=';
var inputSearch = document.myForm.search;
var searchBtn = document.myForm.searchBtn;
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var random = document.getElementsByClassName('random')[0];

random.addEventListener("click" , function(){
  window.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random");
});

function getDataFromInputBox(e){
  console.log("Value Entered"+inputStr);

  if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
      requestData(e);
  }
}
function requestData(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target);
    var inputStr = document.getElementById("txt_search").value;
  if(inputStr != ""){
    console.log(inputStr);
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if ( request.readyState === 4 ) {
      if ( request.status === 200 ) {
        var dataObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var titles = dataObj[1];
        var descriptions = dataObj[2];
        var links = dataObj[3];
        document.getElementById("results_stats").innerHTML = "<h2><span>" + links.length + "</span> results for \"" + "<span>" + inputStr + "</span>" +"\" </h2>"; 
        list.innerHTML = "";
        for ( var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++ ) {
          var li = "<li><a target='_blank' href=" + links[i] + ">" + titles[i] + "</a></li>";
          list.innerHTML += li;
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log("Server responded with following error code : " + request.status);
      }
    }
  };
  request.open("GET" , url + inputStr);
  request.send(null);
  //e.preventDefault(); 
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("results_stats").innerHTML;
    list.innerHTML = "";
    alert("Enter a value");
  }
}

inputSearch.addEventListener("keyup" , getDataFromInputBox);
searchBtn.addEventListener("click" , requestData);
document.myForm.addEventListener("submit",requestData);
```

CSS :-

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* CSS reset ends here */

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;

}

.container-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;

}

header {
    /*background-color: #fc3e5b;*/
    padding: 80px 0;
}

header h1 {
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 70px;
    padding: 30px 0 80px 0;
    color: #fc3e5b;
}

form input , form button {
    padding: 10px 8px;
    font-size: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #fc3e5b;
    outline: 0;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}

form button {
    background-color: #fc3e5b;
    color: #fff;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 32px;
}

h2 span {
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #fc3e5b;
}
.random {
    padding: 22px 7px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0 15px 0;
}

.random:hover {
    border: 5px solid #fc3e6b;
}

#list {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#list li {
    padding: 16px 8px;
    background-color: #fc3e5b;
    margin: 12px 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 22px;
}

#list li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you have to retype what you wrote after pressing enter, I'm assuming that the form is being submitted.

You have a conditional statement that says if the key that is pressed is 13 then `eg.preventDefault ()` but you're not passing the form submit event.

Try this:

```
document.querySelector ('form').addEventListener ('submit', requestData(e));
```